# Spider identification: possible false widow

Tags: bug-identification, spider

We came across a spider here in the UK and we think its a false widow but it doesn't quite look right.
It's approximately 5 cm from front end to back end and the body of it is approximately 2 cm.

The pictures we have of it aren't the greatest, sorry.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The photo is clear, but unfortunately does not show the patterns on the upper surface that would make identification relatively easy.  However, the location is definitely the sort of place that a comb-footed spider (Theridiid) would happily call home.

As for the identification, I'm not a British spider enthusiast, so I can only indicate what I think are useful points.

It's a very interesting looking spider, but has some features that I don't recognize:  the white marks at the leg joints are not something I can remember noticing in any Theridiid I'm familiar with, the possible white spots and fine streaks on the abdomen also don't ring a bell, and the abdomen shape just doesn't look very Theridiid to me, although that may be a function of the spider's pose rather than anything real.

Luckily, the UK is not host to any potentially problem biters (unless you call the painful but not dangerous bites of Steatoda nobilis a problem).  So, you might want to just get the spider into a container where you can view the upper side, photograph that and post the photos to this site or any other that comes to mind - the NHM does identification if you send the photo(s) to bug@nhm.ac.uk .

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply on this John. I have sent an email to bug@nhm.ac.uk and hopefully they can help with this too. I will wait on their reply to see what they and then accept this answer or post my own